# Generating c# file from xsd during runtime for wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, xsd

I'm not sure if this is possible or even a good approach but I have a WPF application that uses a c# class generated from an xsd file. This class was generated manually by using xsd.exe in the terminal. What I am looking to do is generate this class during runtime. The reason I am looking to do this is to give the option to update the xsd without having to generate a new c# file manually and the code working with updated xsd class.

PS. I do recognize this may not be the best idea considering if someone changes the xsd too much it may break the code that relies on that class (assuming this is possible in the first place).

Comment: While it is totally possible to do this (run xsd.exe, compile the resulting cs), why would you like to do this. xsd.exe ist about providing typed access to XML data but when you load a dynamically created class, you won't be able to do much with is except by reflection. Also, I would have security concerns loading code generated from potentially untrusted input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Klaus as to the advisability of doing this, it is not difficult to run xsd.exe from with your code. Something like this will do the trick:

---

```
namepace SomeNameSpace
{
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public static class SomeClassName
    {
        public static void InvokeXsd(string[] args)
        {
            var command = "xsd.exe"; // Note: need path to exe
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command, args)
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            Process.Start(startInfo)?.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you both are right... I think instead of my approach I will check the date of both files and if the xsd is newer than the class file I will throw an error to let the dev know to update the class/dependent code. Although I do appreciate your answer greatly as I didn't know you can run commands from c# I was looking into running a .ps1 file on startup. Thanks!